# Help with creating a demo website

Tags: html, wysiwyg

I have a question of how to develop a small website which is quick and easy which has html support unlike google sites. For one of my course project I have to develop a prototype of the website but just html pages. Want to implement the clicks, text fields, checkboxes etc., I have created a small site of googlesites but that doens't allow me to put the html like text fields radio buttons etc., I just wanted to know if there is any free WYSIWYG capable for doing my stuff.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I dont want to use the div tags and arrange the location of HTML. I just want to drag and drop the fields and the site should automatically place the fields appropriately on the webpage something as easy as google sites

Comment: What does "html support" mean? Why do "google sites" not have this? [edit: oh, "google sites" is some tool, and it doesn't support the entering of _arbitrary_ HTML?]

Comment: Yes, google sites doesn't support the arbitrary HTML. Its just the text and what is supported by the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) to be really useful.  Basically you can put in HTML, CSS, and Javascript, click "Run" and see the result.

It's great for testing or hacking some CSS or Javascript, as it gives you instant feedback, saving you the "edit, save, launch, wait, repeat" cycle you might find using a text or HTML editor.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly.  Perhaps you are looking for a tool *like* Google sites but with more capabilities?  If so, http://www.weebly.com/ is a good option and it is free.

Comment: I was looking exactly for this. Thank you very much